# Problem with deploying Blazor to iis server

Tags: blazor

I created a simple Blazor WASM project and in [Additional information] step, I selected only [Configure for https] and then I published the project into IIS SERVER, but when running website browser of the publishing project, I got an error "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error".

I tried to find for fixing the issue but cannot.
Do you have any ideas? please show me the way. thanks

Comment: What's the event viewer saying? Also, have you installed the hosting bundle?

Answer (score 1):

You should install [URL rewrite2 module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and The [.NET Core Hosting Bundle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) on the IIS server.

For more info, you can refer to [How to deploy a Blazor Application on Internet Information Services (IIS)](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-blazor-application-on-internet-information-services-iis-f96f2969fdcb/)